# java -version throws "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: "

Tags: java

I am using OpenJDK 11 on Debian. Whenever I try to run `java -version`, I get this:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

However, running like this works:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
```

I checked the symlinks, they all worked fine. If `javac` can work, why can't `java`, because both of them are in the same folder. What am I missing?

I get the same when trying to run any compiled classes. I recently tried (but failed) switching to a different JDK, before which I didn't have this problem. My $PATH and $JAVA_HOME are set correctly.

Comment: You should consider researching a good tutorial to download java, it is pretty annoying, and I was getting something like that at first. You have to change a path to specify where your jdk is.

Comment: Does your JDK have the correct file/folder permissions? Also, did you purge/replace the link to the old java executable?

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari All the symlinks are good. What permissions does it require? Also, only 'java' has this problem, 'javac' does not, although they're in the same folder.

Comment: @luke Can you point me to the tutorial that you used?

Comment: @SohailSaha https://youtu.be/IJ-PJbvJBGs this should be a good video, you might consider uninstalling the java jdk you have already and just follow this guys tutorial from start to finish. You could also just jump to the part where he changes the path and try from there however it may be harder and more confusing that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I took a step back, and thought out the exact steps I took when I changed my default JDK. When I had switched to 13, running java would echo a bunch of init settings on my screen, so **I followed somebody's answer to suppress it, and THAT caused the error.**

I had added this line to my .bash_profile to suppress it, and commenting it out followed by a reboot just solved the problem!

```
_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS="$_JAVA_OPTIONS" && unset _JAVA_OPTIONS &&  alias java='java "$_SILENT_JAVA_OPTIONS"'
```

**PRO-TIP: If you're getting such errors, simply check which Environment variables could you have messed up with.**

Comment: Better pro-tip: never copy paste people's advice to suppress or hide errors. Errors should be fixed, not dusted under the nearest furniture

Comment: You have to be real careful when you find sketchy solutions on the net. Really think twice about using them. Any guide that asks you to do stuff like this should explain what it's doing and why it's doing it.

Comment: @OmarAbdelBari I agree.